# The need to check whether a sql query was successful or not?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I really couldn't understand that after a successful connection to the database, what is the need to check whether each query has succeeded or not. How can a query fail if it has been tested before to work properly?

Comment: What happens if your database crashes somewhere between connecting and querying it?

Comment: If your query is an insert statement, what happens if you're trying to insert a record with a duplicate key? (nothing wrong with the query, just with the data)

Comment: What happens if your database server hits a disk space limit?

Comment: Then don't check, set up PDO to throw exceptions instead. Okay, that is basically the same, but easier to manage...

Comment: You need to check if it was successful before you check the results. Wait, you're not checking the results?

Comment: ***Always*** do error checking. What if your query relies on user inputted data and they try something outside of normal? Always make sure that you handle error messaging gracefully for the user.

Comment: I am doing the data validation just before entering so the data part is covered. But checking the query for validation still seems unnecessary because everything from checking whether the data entered by user is empty or is in the format the server expects it is all done before entering the values. In case of getting the data from the server, it seems even more unnecessary.

Comment: So how are you checking your data to prevent duplicate entries?

Answer (score 0):

There is many reasons you should check for success when performing a query.

Here is an example I can think of, You have a registration form and Users can register to your system with their information including a unique `username`.

If a user tries to register with an existing username, the `INSERT` query will fail.

If you don't check for success you will not be able to tell the user that the username already exist.

This is just an example but just keep in mind that you should never assume a query will be successful even if you have tested it. It could be a data type mismatch or a length issue.. or perhaps a wrong date format etc...

So don't get it wrong, it is not unnecessary, it is indeed needed.

Comment: I wanted to know what is the need of checking the success of the query rather than how to check.

Comment: @RohanDhar I misunderstood your question please check my edit